# Google AppEngine entity groups and transactions

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a transaction to work in AppEngine and I'm running into problems with entity groups. My code is a bit like this:

```
parent_obj = ClassA.all().get()

def txn():
  key_name = 'hash of something here'

  if not db.get(db.Key.from_path('ClassB', key_name, parent=parent_obj)):
    obj = ClassB(
      parent = parent_obj
    )
    obj.put()

db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

...but I get the 'Cannot operate on different entity groups in a transaction' error. What I don't understand is that as far as I can see my transaction only operates on entities in the same group. Namely, line 6 queries with a 'parent' which is the same as the 'parent' which is set in line 8, so both queries are concerned with the same entity group.

I'm left to conclude that my understanding of entity groups is wrong. But how? I've read the docs several times and still don't see how what I'm doing is wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably happening because `parent_obj` is `None` **and** you are not passing a `key_name` when creating `ClassB`. In this case, you have multiple entity groups (each entity with no ancestor is a separate group).

This would work if parent_obj is `None` or not:

```
parent_obj = ClassA.all().get()

def txn():
  key_name = 'hash of something here'

  if not db.get(db.Key.from_path('ClassB', key_name, parent=parent_obj)):
    obj = ClassB(
      key_name = key_name,
      parent = parent_obj
    )
    obj.put()

db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

Comment: Thanks very much moraes, I think you're right. In my situation parent_obj was not None though and I became so convinced that what I was doing was right that I pushed my code to the production server and, lo and behold, it worked. So I restarted GoogleAppEngine launcher and it started working locally too. No idea what that's all about!

Comment: Be aware that thers's an error in your code: you are not creating the entity with the given key_name. You are checking if something exists and if not you are creating something different.

Comment: Thanks, that error crept in during the process of simplifying the problem for posting here.